# How to customize java hashset for checking duplication on the basis of set object instance variable value

Tags: java

By default set can not have a duplicate records, but suppose I have class

```
class Employee {
   Integer emp_id;
    String name;
   // other fields and their getter 
  Employee(String name) {
       emp_id++;
   this.name=name;
}
}
```

Now I declare a set in my other class

```
       set<Employee> empSet = new HashSet<Employee>();
      Employee e1 = new Employee ("abc");
      Employee e2 = new Employee ("abc");
```

so while insert it to the set

```
      empSet.add(e1);
      empSet.add(e2);
```

Then first e1 add to set but second e2 returns false.

Now what I want that there is no duplication of their name. So I want to check while insert into set.

Comment: why emp_id is `static` ?

Comment: typed by mistake thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should override the `hashcode` and the `equals` method of `Employee` class.

Where you can ensure the policy of duplication on `equals` method by populating different `hashcode` for different the Objects.

[Find a example of same implementation](http://www.javabeat.net/2007/08/hashcode-and-equals-methods/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use COMPARATOR class to remove duplicates... You have to override compare method... For example code refer this page:http://java2novice.com/java-collections-and-util/treeset/duplicate-objects/

Comment: But I want to do for simple hash set class

Comment: But how you will encooprate your comparator to hashset.because no counstructor for having comparator as argument

Answer (score 0):

As other users mentioned, you need to override hashCode() and equals() methods of Employee class that determines if any two Employee objects are equal/same.

Below is sample implementation for your quick understanding. This would not allow you to add two Employee objects with same name into the Set.

```
public class Employee {
static int emp_id;
String name;
// other fields and their getter 
Employee(String name) {
  emp_id++;
  this.name=name;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int code = name.hashCode();
    return code;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
Employee empObj = (Employee) obj;
if(empObj.name.equalsIgnoreCase(this.name)) {
      return true;
}
return false;
}
}
```

Hope this would be helpful.